# How to organize many Angular.js constants?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on an Angular.js and Rails application, and am using `asset_path(...)` calls for all my templates. Instead of having these littered all over my app, I'd like to have them stored in a single file to make testing easier.

I know of `$provide.constant`, but since each constant has to be injected as a dependency, I have some functions which end up having a long list of dependencies, e.g. my routes file.

Is there a better way to organize my template paths? I thought of making a factory just for holding all my constants, so any controller could just inject the one factory to get any paths it needs.

Comment: You could store any javascript obejct in angular's `constant`, not just a simple string. My be store it like `{ template1: 'foo.html', template2: 'bar.html' }`.